# CAS + LDAP + JSF authentification

Tags: jsf, ldap, cas

I'm doing a project and I'm using LDAP+CAS for authentification.

I created a facade Class for LDAP Query ( to get the user, name & mail ).

My question is : how to test after the authentification if the user is allowed to access to this page & exist in the application database before showing the jsf page. (how can I configure my application to test before showing jsf page).

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I don't know what does CAS mean, but I use JAAS+LDAP+JBoss to Authorize & Authenticate a JSF2 web, I hope this help you:

In your LDAP server create next hierarchy:

```
+ o=your-organization-name (partition) 
   + ou=users (organizationalUnit) 
      - uid=your-id-user (inetOrgPerson), add userPassword attribute 
   + ou=groups (organizationalUnit) 
      - cn=your-user-role (groupOfNames), add the uid before created
```

security-domain on JBoss 7.1 (standalone.xml):

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
            <security-domains>
             ...
 <security-domain name="SecurityRealm" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
                            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://host-ldap-server:port-ldap-server/"/>
                            <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
                            <module-option name="principalDNPrefix" value="uid="/>
                            <module-option name="principalDNSuffix" value=",ou=users,o=your-organization-name"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=groups,o=your-organization-name"/>
                            <module-option name="uidAttributeID" value="member"/>
                            <module-option name="matchOnUserDN" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="false"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
```

in your jboss-web.xml

```
<security-domain>SecurityRealm</security-domain>
```

and the most important: is the user allowed to access to this page? (web.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- Protected Areas -->
    <security-constraint>
         <display-name>Protected</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>              
            <url-pattern>url-pages-you-want-protect</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>your-user-role</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!-- Validation By Form -->
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>your-login-page</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>your-error-page</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <!-- Allowed Roles -->
    <security-role>
        <role-name>your-user-role</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```